# Htaccess changing URL case if directory exists

Tags: php, .htaccess

The problem I am having is that when the URL contains a directory that exists, the URL is getting changed the the case of the file.

More specifically, this is what is happening:

When I go to `domain.com/cron/xxx` then in my PHP script, `uri` will be:

```
cron/xxx
```

But if the folder `Cron` exists, then `uri` will be:

```
Cron/xxx
```

Does anyone know what causes this to happen?

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

RewriteEngine On

```
#remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=api/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm a big amateur, but in middle-time waiting for a pro, wouldn't the problem be case insensitivity of a Windows server, where it just kindly points out the true case of letters? You could try it by trying to create two folders only with cases different, e.g. `test` and `TEST` and see if you indeed got two separate folders.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The thing is that the folder should be irrelevant. If I go to the url `domain.com/test`, I want to route the uri `test`; but if the folder `TEST` just happens to exist, then the uri variable will contain `TEST`, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Do you have mod_speling enabled?

Comment: Are these options set like this: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`?

Comment: Mod_speling is not enabled and enabling those options had no affect.

Comment: Have your resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super versed in ModRewrite, but you could try:

```
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
```

and then use it in your rule like so:

```
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```